# Need Help for Regular Expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I need your help to write a regular expression in Java that match a word inside some text, I need to return all the line where is present the correct match. Each line is present inside a HashMap. I'll call the word to find "var", I'll try to write some examples:

- **var**=a --> correct match
- **var** =a --> correct match
- **var**= a --> correct match
- **var** = a --> correct match
- SomeText**var**OtherText --> not correct match
- if(**var**) --> correct match
- a =    **var**    ; --> correct match
- select a from **var** where c=d; --> correct match
- **var**1 = 3 --> not correct match

I tryed to write this code but it don't work, because it match expression like "**var**Text", that don't have to match:

```
public static void coinvolgimento_variabile(HashMap<Integer, String> tokens, String var) {
        var = var.trim();
        String pattern_var = "\\W*\\D*\\s*"+var+"\\s*\\D*\\W*";
        String not_pattern1 = "\\w+"+var+".*?";
        String not_pattern2 = ".*?"+var+"\\w+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern_var, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(not_pattern1, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(not_pattern2, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m, m1, m2;
        for(int i=0; i<tokens.size(); i++) {
            m = p.matcher(tokens.get(i));
            m1 = p1.matcher(tokens.get(i));
            m2 = p2.matcher(tokens.get(i));
            if(m.matches()==true && m1.matches()==false && m2.matches()==false) {
                System.out.println("Trovata var "+var+": "+tokens.get(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
    }
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd remove the part about the `Map` unless it's strictly relevant, and add more examples of what should be matched and what shouldn't. For instance, do you **only** want `"a"` to be matched in case it's followed by `" = "`? Or preceded by `"; "`? Etc. Then, what do you want to return? Only a `boolean` indicating whether a match occurs or not? Or the whole expression parsed? Or part of it? Etc.

Comment: I'm confused about the bullet point `if(a) --> correct match a = var ; --> correct match` Should this be two bullet points? If so, why is the first one a match when it does not contain "var"?

Comment: This is still a little confusing to me. I'd recommend adding some concrete examples (both positive and negative), and disambiguating the line where two correct matches are stated. Also you probably have attempted a pattern or two, you might want to post those.

Comment: How come `if(a)` is a correct match ?

Comment: Sorry, typing error.

Comment: Added other infomation. Tell me if you need other more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to find below string in a line

```
\bvar\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IUZTic/6) with regex explanation

Comment: Remeber that regex in Java uses double backslashes. Here is one [code](http://ideone.com/6Y1b7V) example